# AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'run_eagerly'

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

When i am trying to use tensorboard, i am getting an error.

```
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

import datetime
log_dir="logs\\fit\\" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir,histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True,write_grads=True)

history = model.fit([text_train, school_state_cat_train, project_grade_cat_train, clean_categories_train, clean_subcategories_train, teacher_prefix_train, numerical_train], y_train, epochs = 5, batch_size = 25, validation_data = ([text_cv, school_state_cat_cv, project_grade_cat_cv, clean_categories_cv, clean_subcategories_cv, teacher_prefix_cv, numerical_cv], y_cv), callbacks = [tensorboard_callback])
```

AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'run_eagerly'

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your log dir to something like this.

`from keras.callbacks.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint`